# Как вместо черных полей по бокам установить фон?

Tags: godot, gdscript

При растягивание игры, а также полном ее развертывание (в полный экран), появляются черные поля по бокам. Я бы хотел чтобы на месте этих черных полос был какой-то фон. Может кто подсказать как это сделать?

Вот фото как они выглядят:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из настроек проекта , я сделал только, чтобы в разделе окно были установлены следующие параметры:

```
Режим -> viewport
Соотношение -> keep_width
Сжатие -> 1
```